# xdotool send mouse move action to background window?

Tags: xdotool

I've been using xdotool click and xdotool key with --window $win1 as argument to control a window that's in the background. How can I perform a click on a specific button in the background window? mousemove doesn't accept the --window argument.

Comment: You can send keys to any window, but you cannot click on things that are not on the screen. You will need to bring the window to the foreground first (wmctrl can do this).

Comment: Could you please add more information to your question such as the content of the script you use to control the background? Will your background window always be in the exact same position, have the same size, and be in a specific virtual desktop/viewport? Which OS and environment are you using?